# open new terminal tab in the same directory with the active tab

Tags: terminal, command-line

In GNOME Terminal of Ubuntu when you open a new tab the new shell will automatically start you in the current working directory of the active tab shell.

E.g. if in the active tab shell I am on `~/myproject` and I open a new tab, the new shell will start on `~/myproject` too.

As you can guess, this is very convenient when you work deep in the directory hierarchy.

Can I configure the OSX terminal to have this behaviour?

If not, is there any free (cocoa) terminal that does this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use [iTerm2](http://sites.google.com/site/iterm2home/) and just select in preferences to "reuse previous tab's directory"

[image]

Comment: I also recommend using iTerm2 as a Terminal replacement. I did come from the linux world, and finding a good gnome-terminal replacement for mac was a must.

Comment: I'd like to add that this behavior can be configured in recent versions of Terminal.app as well.

Answer (score 3):

In recent OS X versions (Mavericks and Yosemite, not sure about earlier versions) in the Terminal.app preferences, "General" tab, there are options for "New windows open with" and "New tabs open with":

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Here's [my solution](https://superuser.com/questions/127117/spawn-a-new-terminal-window-mac-os-x/127125#127125) from a [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/q/127117/51)

---

Get the current environment in your clipboard:

```
env | pbcopy
```

Open up a new Terminal window and export those environment variables

```
for env in `pbpaste`; do export $env; done
```

And to ease the process, you could always alias it, like so

```
alias get_env="env | pbcopy"
alias set_env="for env in `pbpaste`; do export $env; done"
```

So that all you have to do is

> get_env <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> set_env

---

The accepted solution:

```
#!/bin/sh 
osascript <<END 
tell app "Terminal" to do script "cd \"`pwd`\"" 
END
```

Place it in one of the folders in your path, make it executable (`chmod +x filename`). You can then run the name of this script to open a new terminal window in the same directory.

Comment: The `osascript` approach is nice. But it opens the shell in a new window instead of a new tab.